# Error when creating a new user from a template in django

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views, django-admin

I am creating a form so that users can register together with their data in a profile model, the problem is in the Category field which is ManyToMany and gives me error when saving.

This is my form.

```
class UserForm(UserCreationForm):

negocio   = forms.CharField(max_length=30)
encargado = forms.CharField(max_length=30)
imagen    = forms.ImageField()
direccion = forms.CharField(max_length=30)
telefono  = forms.DecimalField(max_digits=15, decimal_places=0)
email     = forms.EmailField()
categoria = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=Categoria.objects.all())
lat       = forms.CharField(max_length=30)
lng       = forms.CharField(max_length=30)
```

These are my models.

```
class Perfil(models.Model):#Este es el perfil del usuario(solo existe uno por cada usuario)
user           = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name='profile') 
nombre_negocio = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
encargado      = models.CharField(max_length=50,null=True,blank=True)
imagen         = models.ImageField(upload_to = 'perfiles',null=True,blank=True)
direccion      = models.CharField(max_length=100)
telefono       = models.DecimalField(max_digits=15, decimal_places=0,null=True,blank=True)
email          = models.EmailField()
category       = models.ManyToManyField(Categoria)
inicio         = models.DateTimeField(null=True,blank=True)
final          = models.DateTimeField(null=True,blank=True)
lat            = models.CharField(max_length=50,null=True,blank=True)
lng            = models.CharField(max_length=50,null=True,blank=True)


def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if not self.id:
        self.slug = slugify(self.nombre_negocio)
    super(Perfil, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

def __unicode__(self):
    return self.nombre_negocio




class Categoria(models.Model):

name   = models.CharField(max_length=50)
slug   = models.SlugField(editable=False)
imagen = fields.ImageField(upload_to = 'categorias',null=True,blank=True,dependencies=[
    FileDependency(processor=ImageProcessor(
        format='JPEG', scale={'max_width': 200, 'max_height': 150}))
])

def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if not self.id:
        self.slug = slugify(self.name)
    super(Categoria, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

def __unicode__(self):
    return self.name
```

This is my view.

```
class RegistrarUsuario(FormView):
form_class    = UserForm
template_name =  'home/registrar.html'
success_url   = '/registrar'

def form_valid(self,form):
    user = form.save()
    email = form.cleaned_data['email']
    direccion      = form.cleaned_data['direccion']
    nombre_negocio = form.cleaned_data['negocio']
    category       = form.cleaned_data['categoria']
    encargado      = form.cleaned_data['encargado']
    telefono       = form.cleaned_data['telefono']
    imagen         = form.cleaned_data['imagen']
    lat            = form.cleaned_data['lat']
    lng            = form.cleaned_data['lng']
    user_profile = Perfil(user=user,nombre_negocio=nombre_negocio,encargado=encargado,imagen=imagen,direccion=direccion,telefono=telefono,email=email,category=category,lat=lat,lng=lng)

    user.save()
    user_profile.save()

    return super(RegistrarUsuario, self).form_valid(form)
```

And I do not know how to do to save the data in the category field well.

Comment: If you get an error, you should tell us what it is.

Comment: Sorry friend, the problem is the category category. TypeError at /registrar/

'category' is an invalid keyword argument for this function

Answer (score 1):

You can't assign many-to-many fields when instantiating the model, because those are stored in a separate table and so need the items to be saved first. Take it out and assign it afterwards:

```
user_profile = Perfil(user=user,nombre_negocio=nombre_negocio,encargado=encargado,imagen=imagen,direccion=direccion,telefono=telefono,email=email,lat=lat,lng=lng)
user_profile.save()
user_profile.category.add(*category)
```